# Get multiple frames at given times

Tags: ffmpeg

Currently I'm getting/storing multiple frames(as bitmaps) from a video by running 3 different commands:

```
String[] a = {"-ss", first, "-i", VideoPath, "-vframes", "1", directoryToStore + "/" + "thumb1.bmp"};
String[] b = {"-ss", second, "-i", VideoPath, "-vframes", "1", directoryToStore + "/" + "thumb2.bmp"};
String[] c = {"-ss", third, "-i", VideoPath, "-vframes", "1", directoryToStore + "/" + "thumb3.bmp"};
```

The problem with this is that it is taking to much time.

Is it possible to do the above with one command, by giving 3 different times from where the frame must be taken from and giving each a unique name?

Or am I doing something wrong that is causing it to run slow?

Comment: How long is it taking?

Comment: @Gyan Almost 10 seconds per image `00:00:09.62`

Comment: What video format? Are you reading it over a network?

Comment: @Gyan `mp4` no the input comes from the device.. I'm running it on android.